# 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'

Tags: android, gradle

As of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0` you'll get `'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.`

This is my build file:

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "store", "api"

    productFlavors {
        googleplay {
            flavorDimension "store"
        }

        amazon {
            flavorDimension "store"
        }

        pre21 {
            flavorDimension "api"
        }

        post21 {
            flavorDimension "api"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to fix it one has to rename flavorDimension simply to dimension.

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "store", "api"

    productFlavors {
        googleplay {
            dimension "store"
        }

        amazon {
            dimension "store"
        }

        pre21 {
            dimension "api"
        }

        post21 {
            dimension "api"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't need to change "flavorDimensions "store", "api" to "dimension "store", "api"" ?

Comment: @Tsunaze nope we don't `flavorDimensions` will stay and is not deprecated

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `flavorDimensions` in the android {} is deprecated for me.

Comment: Same, `flavorDimensions` in `android {}` still shows as deprecated. Android Studio 22022.3.1 Patch 2, API 34